# How to separate instances in rails console query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

Newb on first site.   Is there any way to separate instances when doing a query in development rails c?

Answer (score 0):

Easy, type in:

`bundle exec rails c -s`

and that is it.

```
$ bundle exec rails c --help
Usage: rails console [environment] [options]
-s, --sandbox                    Rollback database modifications on exit.
-e, --environment=name           Specifies the environment to run this console under (test/development/production).
                                 Default: development
```